# Why is free() not working inside a block or in another thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am using the Manatee Barcode Scanner SDK and it requires me to write this code to decode the captured image:

```
unsigned char *frameBuffer = malloc(width * height);
memcpy(frameBuffer, baseAddress, width * height);
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    unsigned char *pResult=NULL;
    int resLength = MWB_scanGrayscaleImage(frameBuffer,width,height, &pResult);
    free(frameBuffer);

    ...
});
```

For some reason the `free(frameBuffer)` call is not freeing the memory and I have a memory leak. After a few hours of running, the application crashes with a Memory Error.

In Instruments I can see the memory leak:

[image]

[image]

Can this be a problem because I am trying to use `free()` inside a block? Or because it runs in another thread?

I have tried adding a `__block` like this:

```
__block unsigned char *frameBuffer = malloc(width * height);
```

But it does not help.

I have tried moving the first 3 lines of code inside the block:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    unsigned char *frameBuffer = malloc(width * height);
    memcpy(frameBuffer, baseAddress, width * height);
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    unsigned char *pResult=NULL;
    int resLength = MWB_scanGrayscaleImage(frameBuffer,width,height, &pResult);

    free(frameBuffer);

});
```

But this gives me problems with `CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);`

Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at `frameBuffer` where you `malloc` it and where you `free` it and make sure that there's nothing that might be resetting `frameBuffer` elsewhere.

Comment: Not sure if malloc is thread safe, you can use dispatch_async to call free(imageBuffer) in main queue.

Comment: Malloc() is thread safe.

Comment: Rob, as you can see, frameBuffer is created as a local variable, used and then freed. There is no other part of the code where frameBuffer appears.